# C# update object within foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

I would like to say this was working and now it is not. I don't know what would have changed.

```
        var inquiry = repo.GetByInstanceId(2);

        foreach (var s in inquiry.Prop)
        {
            s.Prop = "Test 1 2 3...";
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(true, inquiry.S.Single().IsDirty, "S Should Be Dirty");
```

What is happening is before the Property object would get updated and everything would be grand. Now the Property is being updated within the foreach loop but after the foreach loop it's like I didn't do anything.

--EDIT--
Okay, I thinks IsDirty is throwing everyone off. I wanted to put the exact code, minus a few name changes. But IsDirty is not important here.

A basic representation of what I am doing is this:

```
        class test { public int check { get; set; } }

        var x = new List<test>();
        x.Add(new test(){ check = 1});

        foreach (var y in x)
        {
            y.check = 5;
        }
```

the Question is "Shouldn't this work?" I think it should, if not why? I had this working and I don't know what I have changed. I could show you my objects but I would have to modify the names so much it would be pointless. IsDirty isn't the problem. The value I am changing is changed inside the loop but not changed outside the loop.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Its really hard to know what you are asking without the context of your application.

Comment: We need to see the code that sets the Prop and IsDirty properties.

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope that is better

Comment: In the foreach loop y is a local variable that is assigned a value from the List setting y to a different value does not change the list.  However that is not the same as your original post where a property is set.  In short we need to see the code for Prop and IsDirty.

Comment: what is the difference between a y and a property, should the property work?? I need to and was modifying the item from inquiry within the foreach loop using the iterator

Comment: Your updated code is worse - you can't assign to primitive variable created by a foreach and expect it to mean anything after the foreach

Comment: Basically y is a reference to the object in the list changing y doesn't change the object in the list.  It just points y to a different object.  However changing a Property on y (if it had one) would change the Property of the object in the list because y references that object.  (this glosses over the difference between value and reference types, but should get you thinking on the right track)

Comment: The second example is simply illegal code. It won't even compile. I'm removing it.

Comment: I think you need to revisit IsDirty() again.  Take the time to humor us and explicitly rule it out as a cause.  How about just dumping `inquiry.S.Prop` and see if it's what you expect?

Comment: @Pete I'm wondering if the `.S` is a typo and he meant `inquiry.Single().IsDirty`

Comment: Your newly added code is fine. Seriously, we can't help you if you keep on pasting code that is not containing the actual problem

Comment: @juharr: Same problem.  Check the VALUE of .Single().Prop instead of IsDirty.  They need to rule out the possibility that the property was set correctly and the IsDirty() code is misbehaving.

Comment: Does this require that you enable some sort of change tracking somewhere? For example, in entity framework, unless tracking is enabled, the object state will remain "unchanged" even when the object is modified. Could it be similar in whatever ORM (I assume that's what this is) you are using?

Comment: after all this years... i think it might be related to AsQueryable. change in there somehow doesn't directly apply. you might need to replace the root variable with a new AsQueryable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your added explanation you create a copy in y and modify the copy.

This happens when the type of the list items is a ValueType

Comment: okay, but what if it is an instance of a class? that is what it really would be

Comment: If it is a ReferenceType then it should work. Really, if you keep on changing the information and examples we keep on shooting at a moving target. Do not ask us to answer questions about code we can't see.

Comment: I am trying only to refine the examples to give a more accurate picture of what I am trying to do. I will make one more edit and that will be the last one.

Comment: @user, the second example is not like the first and I removed it. The second example is illegal, you cannot modify the loop variable. The first example is modifying a property of the loop variable, which is fine as long as it's a class and not a struct.

Comment: Some advice for the next time you ask a question: it is ok to give a simpler example but make sure it compiles and has the SAME bug.

Comment: The second example was bad, I appoligize for that it was error in my haste to refine the question. The new second example works on my computer. It is over simplified but the Assert passes. I don't know that I will be able to get a proper answer on here since the basis for my thinking is correct so I will just have to fudge with the code I have. Thanks everyone for trying to help.

Comment: yeah, that is true which is my problem, the concept works fine but no the implementation. So I have to figure out what I have screwed up.

Comment: That is why I asked you to post the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be involved with `GetByInstanceId`. If that is returning an `IEnumerable` then it is likely that your foreach is running through the values and making the change, but then your call to `Single` is reiterating and losing your changes.  You might want to do a `ToList` after `GetByInstanceId`.  Of course this is base on the assumption that `inquiry.S.Single().IsDirty` is a typo and should be `inquiry.Single().IsDirty`.  Otherwise we need more info.